# It is possible to inject method in url parameters from client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it was possible from client side to execute an arbitrary method in url parameters ?

I'm in charge of securing an asp mvc application and I want to make sure that there's no problem.

Comment: Would you be able to add an example of the vulnerability?  Perhaps some JavaScript client-code that would exploit the use of the param name?  Plus, in ASP.NET it is best practice to always validate on the server side - client side validation is best for fast feedback to the user, and for security server-side validation must be used to protect against user input from being used blindly to drive your logic or be passed directly to other parts of the application - search for "sql injection" for an example of this type of vulberability.

Comment: @qxotk He is using Reflection on user input. In a WebServer. How the heck **do you not see** the Vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, totally possible. If you give a string, [Reflection](https://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/) can be used to find the function by its name. And call it with whatever argument you want.

However, it is an *insanely dangerous* security vulnerability, not made any better by the fact that this is a WebServer. Feeding user input into a switch/case that at least does some filtering/limits available functions - the closest to this I would ever go.

SQL Injections are bad. But this is like putting a venous cathether in and then allowing random people and their kids near it to inject whatever they want into your bloodstream.

Comment: the question was fit for your answer why not vote up the question?

Comment: could you give an example with this kind of exploitation?

Comment: @qxotk I do not understand your question. I should upvote the question every time I make a answer?

Comment: @Veiz I honestly do not know how this will be abused. It is not a combinaton I ever expected to expierence, so I never thought up any examples. And there are actually too many ways to exploit it. | "A securty vulnerability was found, that allows a attacker to execute random code." - Text of all critical windows securiy vulnerabilities ever. Usually those were caused on someone allowing a buffer overflow or underflow to occur. But this one is actuall SOP.